# WordPress menu problems

Tags: html, css, wordpress, menu

I'm making a WordPress theme and I'm using the default menu structure on the .php file:

```
<nav id="menu" role="navigation">
         <!--  <div id="search">
             <?php get_search_form(); ?>
         </div> -->
     <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'main-menu' ) ); ?>
 </nav>
```

But when I get to the CSS I can't make the elements 100% height inside the nav element, which I gave 80px.

This is my CSS:

```
#menu {
height: 80px;
background-color: aquamarine;
}

.menu {
height: 80px;
}

#menu ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 100%;
list-style-type: none;
list-style-image: none;
}

#menu li {
height: 100%;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 1em;
float: left;
list-style: none;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}

.menu ul li a {
height: auto;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
padding: 30px;
color: white;
-webkit-transition: background-color 600ms ease-out;
-moz-transition: background-color 600ms ease-out;
-o-transition: background-color 600ms ease-out;
transition: background-color 600ms ease-out;
}

.menu ul li a:hover {
background: #0f5972;
}
```

see the little border top and bottom?
[image: see the little border top and bottom?]

Comment: Have you checked the HTML inspector in your browser - does it offer any clues?

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML `menu` is an ID for its DIV, in three of the CSS rules you wrote it as a class - `.menu` instead of `#menu`. That might be a reason.

Comment: .menu is the class Wordpress adds to the <ul> it outputs